# Is core data performance better with less attributes?

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, denormalization

I have a core data entity called DiveSite that has a large number of attributes of which many are booleans that represent features or conditions affecting a dive site.

In fact, I have so many attributes that xCode gives me a warning - "Misconfigured Entity  - DiveSite has more than 100 properties; consider a more shallow entity hierarchy or denormalize properties"

Many of these properties could be grouped reducing the overall number of attributes on the entity - I could possibly change groups of booleans into a series of integers and do a logical and  to check the factors i want.

I also realise that I could make these groups into separate entities - some of which would have a 1-1 relationship and some a 1-many relationship

In terms of performance would changing my DiveSite entity to have fewer attributes be a positive thing to do?

If so would it likely be better performance-wise to have separate entities or to have perhaps 6 attributes which I call using a predicate to filter on. ?

Thinking about it whilst phrasing this question, I realise that if I go the separate entities route I allow myself to add factors to some of the entities just by adding them as instances of the entity without changing my code.

I may have answered my own question as I write this but would appreciate the opinions of experience core data /and database users out there

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's adviced to keep your entities small. When you have a list view for example, you generally don't need all the information on the objects, but when you click one and go to the detail view, you would want to fetch more detailed information. Then you can fetch it from the other entities.

Of course, you should make relationships between these entities.

Comment: So, when you fetched an entity all attributes got populated along with it?

Comment: Yes, It fetches the whole entity.

Comment: I think the situation is a bit more complicated. Core Data fetches all property values (if `includesPropertyValues` is `YES`, which it is by default), and stores them in the row cache. The managed objects will be returned as faults, and only later be populated with the values from the row cache. You can change this behavior by setting `returnsObjectsAsFaults` to `NO`. That said, splitting your entity up sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Retrieving objects as faults is usually more intensive if any property from the collection is needed which is usually the case. That causes the N+1 query problem, where we fetch the objects as faults in one query, and later issue one query per object to fault it in.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say if it's a good practice to keep the entities "small" or not. But from my experience with Core Data, big entities aren't an issue.

By big, I mean an entity with 25 to 50 attributes, with per example a lot of long strings or binary data. The query time is, for entities of that size, more often than not, greater than the load and instantiation time. Fetching 1000 full entities in one fetch is usually faster than fetching 1000 partial entities then faulting 100 missing attributes.

On a side note, I must add I very rarely used entities of that size in a shipping product. Large entities are almost always refactored in several smaller related entities.

Now you told you reached something like 100 attributes. Wow. I think I never hit that mark in any of my projects - Core Data or any "classic" database. I would say the first issue here is readability & maintainability. I'm pretty sure you can refactor such a big entity in smaller ones, define the core attributes defining the principal entity, find some shared values here and there, etc. That would certainly helps.

Performance wise, as always, the answer lies in the profiler to accurately measure where the time is spent. Fetching too many happens, but fetching too little (aka loads of queries) happens more often in my experience.